# Using jQuery in DOM manipulation of NodeJS-Express app

Tags: jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a first nodejs application and I need to use jquery for DOM manipulation. I installed **bootstrap** via *npm* and my browser reports that both bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap.min.css are successfully loaded.

I execute `npm i bootstrap` in my project directory. And loaded bootstrap in my js file using `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist'));`.

I include both bootstrap js and css in the handlebars script I am using to display my application. The css takes effect and styles my app but I can't get my jquery code right. The code below is the contents of my handlebar file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <script language="javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    {{ my-content-outputing-here }}
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(body).hide();
</script>

<script>
    jquery(document).click(
        function(){
            alert( 'success' );
        }
    );
</script>
```

**$** and **jquery** are not recognised and trigger errors:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

While I understand what the issue is, I haven't been able to resolve it.

**UPDATE: contents of bootstrap/dist**

```
node_modules/bootstrap/dist
├── css
│   ├── bootstrap-grid.css
│   ├── bootstrap-grid.css.map
│   ├── bootstrap-grid.min.css
│   ├── bootstrap-grid.min.css.map
│   ├── bootstrap-reboot.css
│   ├── bootstrap-reboot.css.map
│   ├── bootstrap-reboot.min.css
│   ├── bootstrap-reboot.min.css.map
│   ├── bootstrap.css
│   ├── bootstrap.css.map
│   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   └── bootstrap.min.css.map
└── js
    ├── bootstrap.bundle.js
    ├── bootstrap.bundle.js.map
    ├── bootstrap.bundle.min.js
    ├── bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map
    ├── bootstrap.js
    ├── bootstrap.js.map
    ├── bootstrap.min.js
    └── bootstrap.min.js.map
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not added the jQuery script at the header part that you need to include.

```
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

That you need to add.

Second, you need to let the DOM ready before executing your jQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).click(
        function() {
            alert( 'success' );
        }
    );

});
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I want to have jquery locally rather than using a CDN. I thought bootstrap already comes with an installation of jquery to use locally? I can confirm. I pasted a printout of my bootstrap module to confirm the presence of jquery

Comment: @sisko jQuery does not come with bootstrap. You need to install it through `npm i jquery` or through CDN.